How to handle past “unknown race” category when comparing current student demographic percentages to those in the past?
When comparing current student demographic percentages to those in the past how do you handle the past “unknown race” category?
For the years with students in the unknown category, how do you calculate percentages if you only have two categories: white and POC?

Presumably, you are interested in comparing the proportions of all students rather than just those who reported race. What precludes treating unknown as a third category?

Why doesn't the "unknown" category appear in recent data? How was the data collected before? It may be crucial to know that in order to offer a relevant solution. You should look if there is any documentation attached to the data you're using, that could give you useful information relative to that.

I suggest to close this question, as I think it's difficult to offer a useful solution without knowing the details of the data collection process. This question was asked 10 days ago, the original poster isn't registered and didn't answer to @dimitriy 's request for more details, so in my opinion they are unlikely to come back to improve the question. Keeping this question open might prevent other people from asking similar, more detailed questions.
